# Which library generates the "zip" binary (not libzip.so)?

Tags: c, linux

I want to compile my own version of `/usr/bin/zip` binary. I did a search on the web and found source code repo for `libzip`, but the compilation result is a bunch of `libzip.so`, missing the `/usr/bin/zip` binary. Which library should I search instead?

Comment: Check which package installs the `/usr/bin/zip` binary. Then check the information about that package to find out what it's built from.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is here: http://infozip.sourceforge.net/Zip.html#Sources  and the source code is here: https://sourceforge.net/projects/infozip/files/Zip%203.x%20%28latest%29/3.0/